# wpf datagrid icollectionview sorting BUG?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, icollectionview

maybe someone can help me? I have the following scenario:

1. A simple view:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="DataGridSortBug.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
       <DockPanel>
           <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
               <Button Click="Button_Click">Refresh</Button>
           </StackPanel>

           <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding View}" />
      </DockPanel>
   </Window>
   ```
2. The code behind:

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           DataContext = new ViewModel();
       }

       public class TestItem
       {
           private int _sequence;
           public int Sequence
           {
               get { return _sequence; }
           }

           public TestItem(int sequence)
           {
               _sequence = sequence;
           }
       }

       public class ViewModel
       {
           ObservableCollection<TestItem> _collection;

           private ICollectionView _view;
           public ICollectionView View
           {
               get { return _view; }
           }

           public ViewModel()
           {
               _collection = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
               _collection.Add(new TestItem(5));
               _collection.Add(new TestItem(2));
               _collection.Add(new TestItem(4));
               _collection.Add(new TestItem(3));
               _collection.Add(new TestItem(1));

               _view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_collection);
               _view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Sequence", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
           }


       }

       private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           DataContext = new ViewModel();
       }
   }
   ```

After the program startup the datagrid contains (as expected):

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

After click on the button:

> 5
>   2
>   4
>   3
>   1

But I really can't understand why. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? And if this is a bug is there a workaround?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/671505/datagrid-does-not-sort-after-recreating-viewmodel

Comment: A rather old thread... but it's never to late to add a solution/workaround, is it? Well, I've run into the same problem and here's my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177351/wpf-datagrid-ignores-sortdescription

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this bug. (Or at least I presume it is a bug).

When debugging, you can see that the SortDescriptions collection gets cleared after assigning the ViewModel to the DataContext.

As a work around, I removed the SortDescriptions from the CTOR of the ViewModel and put them within a public method which I then call after assigning the ViewModel to the DataContext.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = model;  // SortDescriptions collection is cleared here.
    model.AddSortDescriptions();
    model.View.Refresh();
}
```

It is far from ideal, however this seems to be the only workaround I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
_view.Refresh();
```

after adding the SortDescription.

Answer (score -1):

Your TestItem is not implementing the IComparable interface so it is not sure of what to compare your objects by.

[MSDN IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx)

Basically you need to add this to your class below.

```
public class TestItem  : IComparable
{
    private int _sequence;
    public int Sequence
    {
        get { return _sequence; }
    }

    public TestItem(int sequence)
    {
        _sequence = sequence;
    }

   public int CompareTo(object obj) 
   {
     if (obj == null) 
          return 1;
     // put comparison logic here
    }
```

Comment: The OP states that the sorting worked the first time the view is generated, so this doesn't make sense.